# DHCP Client on Windows Server 2012 high CPU usage

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, cpu-usage, svchost

svchost.exe was seen to be consuming a lot of CPU time (12%) continuously for weeks on end. It has been determined that its DHCP Client which is causing this.

[image]

I'd rather not disable the DHCP client as I am unsure of what role its playing (the machine has a manually set IP address) but need to address the issue.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and if its okay to disable DHCP client?

Comment: The DHCP client is responsible for registering and updating the DNS A record for the server. Have you tried rebooting the server?

Comment: @joeqwerty: Negative, its a critical service so a reboot is quite a lot of admin to get permission for. Was hoping to resolve the issue manually?